# scaleX CSS property, weird behavior with backgroundColor on Chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I have the following example snippet written in plain React:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        width: "100vw",
        height: "100vh",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          position: "relative",
          width: "100px",
          height: "100px",
          backgroundColor: "red"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            height: "10px",
            width: "1px",
            backgroundColor: "pink",
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            transformOrigin: "left",
            transform: "scaleX(100)"
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

it's a very reduced example from what I'm dealing with cause it's easy to understand.
in the code you can see how I'm scaling a 1px div up by 100, which means it's supposed to be 100px, which it is.
but for some reason on chrome the background color doesn't fill the whole div:

[image]

even though in the inspect it shows that the sizing is correct:

[image]

on Firefox it behaves as expected:

[image]

adding a sandbox example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-pond-636z2j?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have 3 monitors, on each monitor it has a different effect btw

Comment: Looks like you are hitting a cumulative rounding problem or similar. Different effects if you start with 10px and scale 10 or 50px and scale 2.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have scaling in the browser or in the system.
You probably want this `.line` showing to  due to some event (eg `:hover`).
So let the line have full width and `transform: scaleX(0);` until this event occurs:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box-wrapp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box:not(:hover) .line {
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

.line{
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: pink;
  inset: auto 0 0;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transition: transform .4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapp">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```